# Not able to see the contents of NTFS partition

Tags: dual-boot, ntfs, disk

Suddenly in Ubuntu I am not able to see the contents of one of my partitions. They do exist. I am able to see them in Windows but not in Ubuntu. The partition is NTFS.

When I try to mount the partition I am getting `Input/output error`.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switched to my Windows and opened the partition. Made protected system folders and files visible. Then I saw found.000 and found.001 folders. From reading on Stack Overflow I came to know that there is no hard deleting those folders. So I deleted those folders and my problem was solved.